# How to add custom css class to wagtail dashboard buttons

Tags: django, wagtail

How can we add custom classes to wagtail dashboard buttons like 'View Live', 'Edit' Buttons for contents created. When I browse through the core files I noticed core wagtail hooks for admin page like below (I know we are not supposed to edit the core files)

```
if page.live and page.url:
    yield PageListingButton(
        _('View live'),
        page.url,
        attrs={'target': "_blank", 'rel': 'noopener noreferrer', 'title': _("View live version of '{title}'").format(title=page.get_admin_display_title())},
        priority=30
    )
```

If I add `'class':'custom-class'` to `attrs` value then the default class disappears and `custom-class` appears

What is the right way to do this

### Edit (On further investigation)

**Using wagtail hooks**

I created a new wagtail app to register the hook so that I was able to register the button without altering the core files, but now I have two buttons(Duplicate), but I was expecting to edit the existing button's `class` `attrs` values

```
from wagtail.core import hooks
from wagtail.admin import widgets as wagtailadmin_widgets
from wagtail.admin.widgets import Button, ButtonWithDropdownFromHook, PageListingButton

@hooks.register('register_page_listing_buttons')
def page_listing_buttons(page, page_perms, is_parent=False):
    if page.live and page.url:
        yield PageListingButton(
            ('View live'),
            page.url,
            attrs={'target': "_blank", 'rel': 'noopener noreferrer', 'title': ("View live version of '{title}'").format(title=page.get_admin_display_title())},
            priority=30
        )
```

Answer (score 2):

[This portion](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/latest/reference/hooks.html?highlight=wagtailadmin%20css#insert-editor-css) of the documentation should address your need.

Comment: Thanks @Dan Swain but isn't that portion explains the steps for adding custom css file rather than adding custom css class?